# Link between a pdf and a pmf

Tags: probability

Watching [MIT's poisson process](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jsqSScywvMc&t=196s) lecture. And the lecturer writes a formula:

$$f_{Y_k}(t) \delta = P(t \leq Y_k \leq t+\delta)$$

This is awesome. What is a rigorous, general way of writing this? Is it true that for any random variable $X$, its pmf is linked to its pdf by the following?

$$f_X(x) dx = P(x <= X <= x + dx) + o(dx^2)$$

? I just made that up that small o, because I read somewhere that $f_X(x) dx$ is only an approximation of the RHS.